# react-route > redirect to the requested content after login

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router

I work on authentication with react and react-route.
My goals are:

1. login link on the menu bar, user can log in via this link
2. if the user is logged in then i need to display different menu structure at the top of the page
3. if the user refreshes the browser's content then different
   menu needs to be rendered, it depends on the status of the user
   (logged in, or anonymous user)
4. if anonymous user click on a link which is not public then login form needs to be displayed automatically
5. after the successful login process user needs to be redirected to the requested content

My solution works fine (if someone interested in then i will post my codes here).

I have a question related to my last goal, (5). I do not know what is the best practice to send the original requested path info across the layers. The requested path at first appears in App.js (Route). Then it needs to be passed to onEnter method. If it is an anonymous user than requested path needs to be passed to Login component which is displayed and finally after the successful login a redirect needs to be done to the original requested route.

My solution use url parameter to pass the requested original route info to the login component.

Here is my code:

App.js

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
    if (!auth.loggedIn())
        replace({
            pathname: '/login?route=' + nextState.location.pathname,
            state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
        })
}

ReactDom.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
        <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />

            <Route path="login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="login?route=:route" component={Login} />

            <Route path="logout" component={Logout} />
            <Route path="about" component={About} />
            <Route path="profile" component={Profile} onEnter={requireAuth} />
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Login.js

```
import React from 'react';

import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import auth from '../auth/Auth';
import Button from "react-bootstrap/lib/Button";

export default class Login extends React.Component {

    doRedirect() {
        if (this.props.location.query.route)
            this.props.router.push(this.props.location.query.route);
        else
            this.props.router.push('/');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={style.text}>
                <h3>LOGIN FORM</h3>
                <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={() => auth.login("username", "password", this.doRedirect.bind(this))}>
                    Login
                </Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// wrap with the withRouter HoC to inject router to the props, instead of using context
export default withRouter(Login);
```

Is there any better OR more react conform solution to pass the requested uri to Login component?

Thx.

Comment: only one improvement what i can do: replace({
            pathname: '/login',
            query: { route: nextState.location.pathname},
            state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
        })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know react conformed solution.But auth redirect handled it in different way .In Profile page(authenticated user view content) validated the authentication instead of OnEnter in the route.
The perspective give option to anonymous user to render different information in the View.

```js
export default class ProfilePage extends React.Component { 
 
   constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.renderProfile=this.renderProfile.bind(this)
  this.renderAskToLogin=this.renderAskToLogin.bind(this)
  this.handleOnLoginBtnTap = this.handleOnLoginBtnTap.bind(this);
  this.getProfiles = this.getProfiles.bind(this);
  this.reloadProfiles =this.reloadProfiles.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    Profiles: ProfileStore.getAll()
  };
  } 
  
    
  handleOnLoginBtnTap(){
   this.context.router.replace({
     pathname: '/login',
     state: { nextPathname: '/Profile' }
   })
  }
 
  render() {
 const { loginId, authenticated} = Auth.loggedIn()   
 return ( 
   <div>
    {authenticated? this.renderProfile() : this.renderAskToLogin()}
   </div>
  )
  }
  
  
 renderProfile() {
  const { Profiles } = this.state;

  const ProfileComponents = Profiles.map((Profile) => {
   return <Profile  key={Profile.name} {...Profile}/>;
  });
   
  return (
    <div>
    <h4> Welcome to <b>ProfileGroup</b> </h4>    
     <button onClick={this.reloadProfiles}>Refresh!</button>
     <h1> Profile List</h1>
     <ul>{ProfileComponents}</ul>
    </div>
  )
  }
  
  renderAskToLogin() {
    return (
   <div>
   <h4 className='red-txt'>Welcome to <b>Profile Group</b>.You are not yet authendicated. </h4>
   <h4> If you want to login, please tap Login button</h4>
   <button ref='loginBtn' className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleOnLoginBtnTap}> Log In</button>
   </div>
      )
  }
  
}

ProfilePage.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
 }
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. I like your concept very much. I use the same method for rendering my menu content: if (auth.loggedIn()) return <UserMenu /> else <DefaultMenu />. Honestly I do not know why I mixed together the usage of onEnter() method and this approach. Maybe because the articles what I have found in this topic are just suggested to use onEnter(). And  I have not read any article when I wrote my menu component :) I am going to remove onEnter from my route. Anyway what about the original question? Do u have any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

As per my code, In ProfilePage handleOnLoginButton() fired when user tap  the Login. In that handler set the nextpath as current page and redirect to loginpage.
In loginpage ,handleOnLoginBtnTap() event handle after success login redirect to nextpath present in the state.

```js
//Login Page
 handleOnLoginBtnTap(){
    console.log("Login validation in progress ..")
    Auth.login(this.state.loginId, this.state.loginPwd, (loggedIn) => {
     if (!loggedIn)
     {
      alert("Login Validation failed. login Id and password should be same");
      return;
     }

     const { location } = this.props

     if (location.state && location.state.nextPathname) {
       this.context.router.replace(location.state.nextPathname)
     } else {
      this.context.router.replace('/')
     }
    })
  }
```